# What legal dictionary does the CRA use for business and tax terminology?

Tags: taxes, canada, terminology, canada-revenue-agency

I am currently looking for the technical definition used by Canada's Revenue Agency for these words:

1. Payment
2. Capital Debt Obligation

To determine whether payments made towards my margin loan in my personal brokerage account fall under their definition of these two words or not. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: If you search for "definitions" on the CRA site https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/search.html?q=definitions you will see that there are thousands of pages of definitions which are mostly given specifically to the particular domain they relate to (income tax, employee stock options, etc etc). So I think you would need to find the specific domain and then look for the definitions in that section. Or just contact them and ask?

Comment: @Vicky Can't for the love of me find the definition page for `Payment` or `Capital Debt Obligation`. Tried calling them today and the wait time was 2 hours before immediately disconnecting. 